# Open a word document from javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-word

I have to open a word document from javascript with cross browser support. Then I have to print that document.

```
var objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
objWord.Visible = true;
objWord.Documents.Open(resumePath);
```

But I get reference error for ActiveXObject

Comment: How can a `ActiveXObject` (IE) be cross browser?

Answer (score 0):

Short of implementing a Word parser in JavaScript and converting the document to something universally supported by browsers (such as HTML) — you can't.

Instead, link to the document, allow people to open it in their word processor of choice and use the print functionality that is build into that application.

Comment: Is my need is possible from java?

Comment: A Java applet could do it (so long as it was given the right security permissions so it could print). You'd still need a Word parser written in Java.

Comment: Hi, I opened word from java. Now could you please help me to print it?  `public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {          
          Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop(); 
          File f = new File("C:\\Users\\sarika.sukumaran\\Desktop\\resume.doc");
          desktop.open(f);
    }`